# Changing parameters in Super class in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Assuming I am having the following class which  inherits from `svm.LinearSVC`:

```
class specialSVM(svm.LinearSVC):

     def fit(self,x,y):
        x_new,y_new = a_function(x,y)
        super(specialSVM,self).fit(x_new,y_new)
        return self 

         .
         .
```

So how can I change the default `penalty='l2'` to `l1` or any other parameter?

Comment: Is penalty a variable? A function parameter? What do you mean?

Comment: is a parameter of the class of `svm.LinearSVC`

Comment: You have it, already... a = specialSVM(penalty='l1'). This is because you have inherited everything from LinearSVC, so that has not changed if you haven't defined your own __init__ or anything like that.

Comment: But what if i just want to change only one parameter?? Do I have to initialize all the variables of `svm.LinearSVC`?